# Drawing a deltoid curve in canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, curves

https://jsfiddle.net/prew217o/

As you can see ive tried converting the deltoid formula to code but why isnt it working? I wonder what ive done wrong because the formula is the exact same one as in the wikipedia article.

```
const ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(150, 75);
var t = 0;
var a = 100;
var b = 80;

function y(t) { 
    return (b-a) * Math.cos(t) + Math.acos(((b-a) / a) * t);
}

function x(t) { 
    return (b-a) * Math.sin(t) - Math.asin(((b-a) / a) * t);
}
var nx = 0;
var ny = 0;

function animate() {
    t += 0.1;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(nx, ny);
  ctx.lineTo(x(t), y(t));
  ctx.stroke();

    nx = x(t);
  ny = y(t);
  console.log(ny)
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `arcsin` and `arccos` instead of `a * sin` and `a * cos`. Change your code like so to get a curve that actually looks like a deltoid curve:

```
var a = 20;
var b = 3 * a;

function x(t) { 
    return (b-a) * Math.cos(t) + a * Math.cos(((b-a) / a) * t);
}

function y(t) { 
    return (b-a) * Math.sin(t) - a * Math.sin(((b-a) / a) * t);
}
```

Link to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5mg7d3j/)

PS: The wikipedia article uses `b = 3 * a.` I used the same in my fiddle.

Comment: Hi, I just noticed after drawing the deltoid, it continues drawing the again lines on the exact same spot. You can see that the line gets thicker.

Comment: I think it continues to draw it over and over unless you set a condition for it to stop

Comment: Okay cool, thanks for explaining. Wasn't looking at the code at all, just thought it might have been unwanted.

Comment: ah sorry i interpreted it wrong. I though it was acos